# controls are not working while playing a video when i click on image in html5?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, video

I am playing two videos in HTML5, I have written some Javascript to control the play/pause options. If I click on poster then video is playing. But if I use 2 videos, in this case the play/pause button is not working properly. Sometimes when I click on the second video then the first video is playing.

I would like to apply the controls to videos separately.

```
<video onclick="playVideo()" width="320" height="240" poster="images/Koala.jpg" controls="controls">
        <source type="video/mp4" src="videos/clipcanvas.mp4" />
    </video>
    <video onclick="playVideo()" width="320" height="240" poster="images/Koala.jpg" controls="controls">
        <source type="video/mp4" src="videos/clipcanvas.mp4" />
    </video>
```

Script code:

```
function playVideo() {
        //alert("hello");
        var myVideo = document.getElementsByTagName("video")[0];
        if (myVideo.paused) {
            myVideo.play();
        } else {
            myVideo.pause();
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Obviously it's incorrectly because you always select the same element( the first video el).

So change this line `var myVideo = document.getElementsByTagName("video")[0];`.

1. the easiest way is

   ```
   onclick="playVideo(this)"; // this refer to the correspondingly video el
   function playVideo(myVideo) {
       // var myVideo = document.getElementsByTagName("video")[0]; //remove this
       // do whatever as you like
   }
   ```
2. use other selector instead. e.g. give the two `video` different ids and select by id.